# Controller in $routeProvider.when vs ng-controller in template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, route-provider

New to Angular.js.

What's the difference of passing the controller as

`app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {templateUrl: '/templates/profile/login.html', controller: 'angLoginController'});
});`

vs declaring the controller using ng-controller directive in the template itself?

`<body ng-controller="angLoginController">
   ....
</body>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: Separation of concerns. It would be easier to maintain if you place all controllers respective to the view in the router. You need to edit all in one place.

> In $routeProvider

This gives you flexibility to manage all controllers and views respective to that particular route. In this case you can manage controllers in one place.

> In second case: inside view

if you place it inside individual view, Then you need to go to that view and edit them.

Comment: other than maintainability, they wouldn't have any fundamental difference of loading in time?

Comment: Yes, there wouldn't be any difference.